# Hosting java web application running on internet

Tags: java, mysql, web, hosting, war

I created a web application which used mySQL data connectivity on my local computer.When i host this application on internet i am not able to get the internet host provided database to bind with my application.

The internet host provides with a database which is not MySQL but SQL.

If anyone knows a free hosting website where i can find and bind MySQL database with my server please tell the procedure to do it. and what changes do i have to make in source code to get this going.

My ultimate goal is to run this web application on a internet host as good as it runs on my localhost.Please suggest some other internet host.My application only uses jsp's,javascripts,html,java classes and MySQL database.Any other Ideas are also welcome which fulfills my goal.

Right now my data base connectivity for localhost is:

```
package datalayer;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class DBConnection {
public static Connection getConnection()
{
Connection con=null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///tpcell","root","root");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("getConnection()"+e);
    }
    return con;
}


}
```

Comment: It is not free but digitalocean has offer of vps for $5 per month. You can install any server/ database to your vps.
https://www.digitalocean.com

Comment: What kind of database is your hoster using? Normally you just need to change the java database driver and everything should work again.

Comment: Even if he changes the driver, will the commands written for MySQL work for every SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: an IaaS or a PaaS.

- On an IaaS you will choose the OS that you would like and you will need to install Tomcat, MySQL,... from scratch in a similar way you'd do locally. Sometimes they provide a free tier where you can test how everything is going. Here you have Amazon EC2, Digital Ocean,...
- A PaaS where you can easily, just a click of your mouse, enable services. It means that you could have something like Tomcat as a service or MySQL as a Service without taking care of the installation or the configuration process. They usually provide a free tier where you can deploy your application and also create the database and do the binding.

You have [this](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/09/bind-your-java-application-to-your.html) example which shows you how to do it using JNDI on a specific provider. However, there are some of them, you can always look for the most suitable to your needs.